# GitHub-hosted Jupyter notebook auto line breaks / wrapping

Tags: line-breaking

I would like to put a document containing a fair amount of inline math onto GitHub as an IPython Notebook. Because I don't like the typical Markdown sans-serif font, which wouldn't match the Latex font anyway, I would like all of my text to be in Latex.

The problem is that within the \text{} elements it seems that Latex doesn't automatically add line breaks to fit the width of the page.

For example,

```
$\text{This is an example set of text. Now here is a bit of math text: } S = \{s_1, s_2, . . . , s_n\}, \text{ and here I would like there to be more text. Several sentences may follow, and therefore form a paragraph.}$
```

results in an unnatural line break after the expression for the set S.

Is there any way to: get the text inside the \text{} elements to wrap properly; or have normal-looking text inside "$...$"; or to change the font inside the Markdown portions of Jupiter notebooks? As I said before, the is hosted on GitHub.

Comment: Welcome! I am not sure if this is on topic. How is that code rendered? Is it actually using TeX? In any case, I think that `\text{}` is just not meant for this. It is not intended for paragraphs of body text but only for short pieces of text within maths mode.

Comment: Did you try \mbox{inline math and text}???

Comment: This seems off topic; however, since `\text` makes a box, the text is unbreakable. Forcing math mode for changing the font doesn't seem the best choice and surely some CSS based method exists.